# Autodesk Forge Error 403 when trying to retrieve objects with VSCode Forge Extension

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm getting 403 error in VSCode Forge Extension, get message "No derivztives yet", but i know derivatives are there because the app is working and the Forge Viewer correctly loads and displays the model. Any suggestion?

Comment: a 403 error most of the times means you don't have the right permission to access this file. Are you the owner of that bucket? are you passing the right scopes to your token? Are you using the correct keys in your VS Code env to access those derivatives?

Comment: Thanks i was simply passino the wrong key...

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for letting me know.